# "Ион" или "йон"?

Tags: орфоэпия

В учебниках химии написано "ион (йон)". Но как же все-таки правильно или как предпочтительнее, если правомочны оба варианта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно - ион.
Ранее использовавшееся написание йон (по аналогии с йодом или йогом) неправильно. Уже потому, что не следует орфоэпической норме; в слове "ион" первый звук - гласный и, а не согласный йот.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет об электрически заряженной частице, то - ион. Йон - имя собственное (по данным Википедии). Может быть, какие-то новые веяния?

Answer (score 0):

Говорить ион - просто неудобно. Гласная И автоматически сокращается в Й перед ударной гласной О.

Comment: Есть фамилия Ионов (от Иона). Есть рассказ А П. Чехова «Ионыч», написанный в 1898 году. Неудобно жутко: 120 лет народ терпит, держится как-то.